# PySide6 QAbstractTableView - Set table header color

Tags: python, pyside6

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748460/qtableview-custom-table-model-set-text-color-in-header) which is asking the same as me. However, the solution is not working for coloring my header row. Here is my code

```
    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._dfDisplay.columns[col])
            elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
                return QtGui.QColor(173, 216, 230)  # light blue
            else:
                return None
        return None
```

Why is are my table headers not being colored?
There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837403/qtbackgroundrole-seems-to-be-ignored) but my rows themselves color fine.

Edit: Full Code:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np


class CustomHeaderView(QHeaderView):
    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex):
        painter.save()
        painter.restore()
        brush = QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.blue)
        brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawRect(rect)
        value = self.model().headerData(logicalIndex, Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        print(value)
        painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, value)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._dfDisplay = data
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data[index.column()][index.row()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._dfDisplay.columns[col])
            elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
                return QtGui.QColor(173, 216, 230)  # light blue
            else:
                return None
        return None

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        # self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))  # set theme to fusion to allow coloring of headers -- works
        header_view = CustomHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeader(header_view)
        data = pd.DataFrame([
          [1, 9, 2],
          [1, 0, -1],
          [3, 5, 2],
          [3, 3, 2],
          [5, 8, 9],
        ])

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)


app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Are you using stylesheets? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Updated, and no I am not using stylesheets.

Comment: assuming I need an item delegate

Comment: Setting the stylesheet works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454694/how-to-change-the-header-background-color-of-a-qtableview

Comment: What OS and specific Qt version? What's the output of `QApplication.style().objectName()`? Also, try with `self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`. Or consider using `'windows'` instead.

Comment: Also, the `data()` retrieval is wrong: the main item getter of a dataframe is the column, so it should be `value = self._data[index.column()][index.row()]`. Always remember to test your programs in a terminal or prompt, as you've had spotted that on your own.

Comment: `QApplication.style().objectName()` returns `windowsvista` on windows 8. Fusion did make the color blue. Is there anyway to have the color work in `headerData()` without this? Qt version: 6.5.2 given by `QtCore.qVersion()`

Comment: As far as I can understand no: `windowsvista` is a style that is not based on palette but rather on pixmaps, so it completely ignores palette colors used for drawing and therefore customization of the palette role for the header. You either set another style that supports custom colors, or use a custom QHeaderView and override `paintSection()`. Using a QProxyStyle (overriding `drawControl()` for `CE_Header`) might also work, but you have to be careful about it and you should check the sources in order to get a result that properly resembles the default behavior.

Comment: Okay, since I can set colors after setting the theme to `fusion`, I will go that route since that seems easiest.

Comment: @musicamante should this suffice for a header override, I might go that route: ```class ShortInterestHeaderView(QHeaderView):

    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex):
        painter.save()
        QHeaderView.paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex)
        painter.restore()

        pen = QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.blue)
        brush = QBrush()
        brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawRect(rect)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but the first question you have to ask is: does it suffice for your needs? If it does, then it probably is. In any case, calling `painter.save()` before `paintSection()` is pointless, but I cannot tell you more because code in comments is unreadable, so you either update your question or at least provide a pastebin of your attempt. Right now, that code just seems to paint a full black rectangle (with blue borders) for the section, and that doesn't seem like what you wanted to do, mostly because it completely hides the section text.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems making the theme fusion and setting the color via `headerData` is the only way to go. My CustomHeaderView does nothing. I will update my code now.

Comment: It doesn't work because it has errors (and your code is also missing proper imports): it should be `QHeaderView.paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex)` or, better, `super().paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex)`. Also, as said, if you draw a rectangle *after* the default implementation, you will be painting **over** it. And your `data()` function is still wrong.

Comment: Sorry I had changed in my code but not on SO. Check out my updated painter, I believe it is correct. Thanks for your help btw, means a lot.

Comment: I only need to make the text white, and resize the rectangle (column) to be the size of the text plus some padding and I am good to go.

Comment: All you ask can be answered by reading the documentation about QPainter and QHeaderView.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your help. for those interested, to get the outline white, I needed ``painter.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        painter.drawRect(rect)``` amd to set the width of the header I used ```        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeMode.ResizeToContents)
```

Comment: hey @musicamante can you give me a hint on how to properly align text drawn by an ItemDelegate. I am having the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778029/qstyleditemdelegatepaint-why-is-my-text-not-properly-aligned and the solution is not helping me.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments and don't use them to ask for unrelated questions. If you have a problem and cannot find a similar existing question that helps you, create a new one.